# An operation preserving order on finite field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, order-theory

Let $p\equiv 3(\mod 4)$ be a prime. How to show that there exists an order " $<$ " on the finite field $F:=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ such that the following three conditions hold :

(i) For every $a,b\in F$ , either $a=b$ , or $a<b$ , or $b<a$

(ii) For every $a,b,c\in F$ , $a<b \implies a+c <b+c$

(iii) For every $a,b,c\in F$ , $a<b$ and $0<c \implies ac<bc$

?

Comment: Do you want your ordering to be transitive? Then it would not be possible.

Comment: Have you tried to find an order for small values of $p$, for example $3$ or $7$? It can also help to try it with $5$ and see why it won't work there.

Comment: @MaikPickl : I don't want transitivity

Comment: @Verdruss : I can easily show that an order satisfying my conditions is not possible when $p$ is prime of the form $4k+1$

Comment: Is a < b, b < a a contradiction?  Then 0 < 1, 1 < 2, 2 < 3,.. .

Comment: @WilliamElliot : what ?

Comment: @users. First you want an order, then you do not.  So you want a relation with i, ii and iii.  In i, is 'or' inclusive or exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of basic facts about quadratic residues. Let 
$$Q=\{a^2\in F\mid a\neq0\}.$$
Then we know that

- $-1\notin Q$, here we need the assumption $p\equiv3\pmod4$,
- $Q$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group, in other words $x,y\in Q\implies xy\in Q$,
- $|Q|=(p-1)/2$,
- Together the first and the third bullet imply that if $a\in F$ then exactly one of $a$ and $-a$ is an element of $Q$.

These properties of $Q$ suggest the following "order".

**Definition.**
For $a,b\in F$, we define that
$$a<b\Longleftrightarrow b-a\in Q.$$

Then

1. The fourth bullet implies that if $a\neq b$, then exactly one of the differences $a-b, b-a$ is an element of $Q$. This shows that our order relation has property (i).
2. Because $(b+c)-(a+c)=b-a$ the definition of $<$ immediately implies that our order relation has property (ii).
3. If we assume that $a<b$ and $0<c$, then both $c=c-0$ and $b-a$ are elements of $Q$. By the second bullet $c(b-a)\in Q$, but this implies $ac<bc$ verifying property (iii).

---

I think it is not too difficult to see that this is the only possible order relation. Consider the set of positive elements
$$
G=\{x\in F\mid 0<x\}.
$$
Then

1. Property (i) implies that $0\notin G$.
2. Property (ii) implies that $a<b$ if and only if $0<b-a$ if and only if $b-a\in G$.
3. Property (iii) implies that $G$ is closed under products, and therefore a subgroup of $F^*$.
4. Items 1. and 2. together imply that for $a\neq0$ we have $a\in G$ iff $-a\notin G$.
5. Items 3. and 4. imply that $Q\subseteq G$ because either $0<a$ or $0<-a$ and $(-a)^2=a^2\in G$ in either case.
6. Item 4. says that $G$ has exactly $(p-1)/2$ elements, so item 5. tells us that $G=Q$.